# Display date on news post in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-news

I would like to display the date on news posts. 
The date is being displayed on the news rollup tiles, but when the user opens a news post there is no information available when this news was published.

What would be the recommended procedure to achieve this in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, we won't see the Published date in News Site page.

To enable for the News post, follow the below steps,

- Edit the page.
- Then click the Edit icon button in Title Area
- Then Enable the "**Show Published date**" toggle button.

This enables the page to show published date.

[image]
I'll hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I would never have found this. I was investigating how properties could be added to a new news page template... Way off!

Comment: You know any way to do this via PowerShell or set this as default enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't show the publish date (e.g.; Created, Publish Start Date, or First Published Date), but instead shows:

"Published MM/DD/YYYY" where the date is the MODIFIED date for the page.  This is incredibly misleading for users, as it should either:

1. show one of the other three dates, or
2. say "Modified:" or "Updated:"